# Why does the stealth address involve a hash function?

Tags: cryptonote, stealth-address, cryptography, elliptic-curve

According to the [cryptonote white paper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf), a stealth address of the form P = H_s(rA)G + B. My question is, why is the hash function necessary? It seems that P=rA + B would work just as well. Using a hash function makes scanning the blockchain for your incoming tx's more difficult, since you have to perform a hash for every transaction on the blockchain.

Give two transactions sent to the same user, P_1-P_2=(r_1-r_2)A=a(R_1-R_2), but I don't see how that opens any attack vectors.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your system although the recipient can still find his transaction using *R*, he would also need to know *r* for deriving the corresponding private key.

You could fix that by making *r* also public, and still only the user would be able to derive the private key *ra+b*, but then everyone in the network can figure out that the recipient was the address (*A,B*)... Using the hash eliminates the need to publish *r* and thus preserves the recipient's privacy.

Comment: Ah yes, the private key. Forget about that.